# Dar formato a select múltiple

Tags: css, select, materialize

Quiero agregar un `<select multiple>` a mi HTML, pero no logro encontrar cómo cambiar su color de texto, de fondo, o tamaño de font. Traté en el `div` que lo contiene, pero sólo cambia el background.

```
<div class="col s4 blue white-text">
    <select multiple class="white-text">
        <option value="Color">Topping</option>
        <option value="Blanco">Pepperoni</option>
        <option value="Azul">Onion</option>
        <option value="Verde">Artichoke</option>
        <option value="Rojo">Tomato</option>                            
    </select>              
</div>
```

Comment: En el CSS de Materialize, busca las propiedades que se aplique a la siguente línea de clases: `.dropdown-content li > a, .dropdown-content li > span` con eso ya te das una idea de  lo que necesitas cambiar

Comment: Gracias, voy a probar